# how to update attribute from start() and run() in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I create sub-class from multiprocessing.Process.

Object p.run() can update instance.ret_value from the long_runtime_proc, but p.start() can't get the ret_value updated though long_runtime_proc called and ran.

How can I get ret_value with p.start()?

```
*class myProcess (multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, pid, name, ret_value=0):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.id = pid
        self.ret_value = ret_value
    def run(self):
        self.ret_value = long_runtime_proc (self.id)*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling [`Process.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.run) directly does *not* start a new process, i.e. the code in `Process.run()` is executed in the *same process* that invoked it. That's why changes to `self.ret_value` are effective. However, you are not supposed to call `Process.run()` directly.

When you start the subprocess with [`Process.start()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.start) a new child process is created and then the code in `Process.run()` is executed *in this new process*. When you assign the return value of `long_runtime_proc` to `self.ret_value`, this occurs in the child process, not the parent and thus the parent `ret_vaule` is not updated.

What you probably need to do is to use a pipe or a queue to send the return value to the parent process. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) for details. Here is an example using a queue:

```
import time
import multiprocessing

def long_runtime_proc():
    '''Simulate a long running process'''
    time.sleep(10)
    return 1234

class myProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, result_queue):
        self.result_queue = result_queue
        super(myProcess, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.result_queue.put(long_runtime_proc())

q = multiprocessing.Queue()
p = myProcess(q)
p.start()
ret_value = q.get()
p.join()
```

With this code `ret_value` will end up being assigned the value off the queue which will be 1234.

Comment: Thanks for the repy.



p.run() just runs its proc in main process instead of sub-parallel process, so it can return value to main process. And it's not parallel as I need.



p.start() really invokes a new process but can't transfer value to parent process.

Comment: @xinwu: correct, that's what I said: `p.run()` runs in the same process so you can get the result. `p.start()` runs the `run()` method in a child process. If you read further into my answer you will see that the solution is to use a queue, or some other form of interprocess communication.

Comment: Yes, I can use queue or pipe to get the return value from parallel processes. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: @xinwu: No problem. If I have answered your question you might consider upvoting and accepting this answer.

Comment: It's my first question. Could you show me how to upvote the answer?

Comment: @xinwu: thanks for accepting. To upvote click the up arrow next to the answer. Possibly you don't have enough reputation yet to upvote. No problem anyway.